# How to say *heathenous?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to decry an act or object as having heathen-like qualities. I would call it *heathenous, except apparently this word is neither in the dictionaries nor oft-seen by google.

Comment: The word you are looking for is *heathen*, as JSBangs has noted. The only other adjective is *heathenish*...

Comment: Also, I'm sure you wanted another asterisk after *heathenous* ;)

Comment: @Jimi Oke: No, an asterisk after the word would be a way of marking up emphasis. Preceding a word by an asterisk is conventional notation for a form that isn't correct or attested.

Comment: Why do you want to decry something as having heathen-like qualities?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: why not? =).

Comment: @Claudiu: Do you have an example? What is wrong with heathen? To me the word "heathen" has associations chiefly of parochial Christian xenophobia, but maybe you have another context.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: ah i thought it was really awkward to say "Such speech is heathen!" or "Such actions are heathen!" to me, heathen is really a noun, and that sounds awkward, and would be much better to say "Such speech is *heathenous!" i'm expecting the -ous, pretty much. i don't mind the connotations of the word or whatnot

Comment: @Claudiu You say " to me, heathen is really a noun, Unfortunately, *heathen* has been an English adjective for over 1,000 years: 971   Blickling Homilies. 15  *He bið geseald **hæþnum** mannum.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on the context in which you intend to use it, there are a few options:

- **heathen**: this is also an adjective, so it would seem the most obvious choice
- **pagan**: denotes non-Christian or pre-Christian, with no strong positive or negative connotation per se; in modern times also of a [spiritualist movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paganism#Neopaganism)
- **unchristian**: has a negative connotation: lacking all traditional Christian virtues, especially charity
- **heretical**: denotes being antagonistic to standard thinking
- **barbarous**: connotes cruelty and crudeness
- **barbaric**: connotes being primitive, especially as regards gaudy decoration
- **barbarian**: most neutral word for being uncivilised

Comment: If you want to suggest that the idea is antagonistic to standard thinking in particular "Heretical" is a good word.

Comment: @Glenatron: That is actually much more to the point than my description—I have substituted it for mine.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use "heathen".

> These heathen rites will bring down the wrath of the Flying Spaghetti Monster on our heads.

This doesn't work so well as a predicate, adjective, however. In that context, there is no derivative of *heathen* that will work, so I'd go with *pagan*.

> ? This belief is heathen. [Sounds very odd.]
>
> This belief is pagan. [Sounds fine, means almost the same thing.]

Comment: *This belief is heathen* doesn't sound *very* odd to me. Granted, *heathen* usually modifies *gods*, etc.

Comment: Since there are self-described (neo-)pagans, and I'm not aware (could be wrong) that there are (neo-)heathens, I'd stick with heathen anyway.  I mean that heathen seems to be neutral while pagan could be taken to refer to the mentioned groups.

Comment: @jae, I agree. I think in current practice at least, *heathen* means "not having our religious beliefs", while *pagan* means "having religious beliefs, which are not ours". I.e. the former just says "not Us", while the latter says "Them".

Comment: @Martha, actually I agree, too. The only difference is that I wouldn't normally use the word "heathen" in a modern context at all--it sounds old-fashioned to archaic, and in any context where I *would* use the word "heathen", it would be basically synonymous with "pagan".